# Setting confirm box dimensions

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have a confirm box created with jquery. Actually, I took the code from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!/ and adapted it to my needs. The thing is that i am using it for two different cases. In the first case, it has a large content, so I set min-width: 60%; to ensure that the content will fit. In the second case I have very little content. So I am trying to set its max-width: 20%; to avoid empty space.

For the first case, this is the div declaration:

```
<div id="show_dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
```

and the css:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
position: relative;
border: 0;
padding: .5em 1em;
background: none;
overflow: auto;
min-width: 60%;
}

.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
background: #ffffff url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
color: #222222;
min-width:60%;
}
```

For the second case, I have this declaration:

```
<div id="dialog" class="delete test" title="Action can not be reversed!"></div>
```

And the css:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
position: relative;
border: 0;
padding: .5em 1em;
background: none;
overflow: auto;
max-width: 20%;
}

.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
background: #ffffff url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
color: #222222;
max-width:20%;
}
```

But both boxes have the same width (60%).

I always had a hard time modifying other people's code but this is driving me crazy. Hope I was enough clear. Any ideas on how to set the size properly?

Update: I tried defining the width here

```
$("#dialog").dialog({maxWidth: 20 } );
$("#dialog").html('<p>Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>').dialog("open");
```

Comment: where do you set this both css styles ?

Comment: I am setting it in the same css file (assuming this was your question)

Comment: you can set the width properties when calling the plugin method itself, then why you need to put this in CSS ? http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-maxWidth

Comment: trying to separate style from structure.

Comment: you can better specify it when you calling the dialog method?

Comment: also, i tried that but it doesnt work.

Comment: how you tried, please post the javascript ?

Comment: $("#dialog").dialog({minWidth: 20} );                                                                                  $("#dialog").html('<p>Are you sure you want to deletethis?</p><input type="button" value="YES" id="confirm"></input><input type="button" value="NO" id="reject"></input>').dialog("open");

Comment: please update your question, so it will be more readable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71685/discussion-between-amygrimaldi-and-frebin-francis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dialog` widget's option you're trying to use for a percentage is actually taken in pixels [(ref. maxWidth)](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-maxWidth)

The jQuery way of changing your styles would be with `.css()`:

```
$(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content, .ui-widget-content").css("maxWidth", "20%");
```

Also be aware that since you're using custom size styles you may want to make the dialog non-resizable:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ resizable: false });
```

Comment: vote up for taking care of the resizable issue. But since I am using some ready jquery, there must be something there that causes this issue ... So i will let you know when i solve it